# Text lemmatization in pyspark return a TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: dataframe, text, pyspark, lemmatization, mining

I spent a lot of time trying to find the solution to this one. I am working with pyspark on a text column dataframe that I tokenized, and I am trying to lemmatize it using nltk but this gives back an error: `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`. My code is the following:

```
def lemmatize(fullCorpus):
    lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatized = fullCorpus['filtered'].apply(lambda row: list(list(map(lemmatizer.lemmatize,y)) for y in row))
    return lemmatized
```

The above function works fine until I want to apply it to my dataframe string column:

```
election.withColumn("filtered", lemmatize(col("filtered")))
```

Where election is my dataframe and "filtered" is the column I would like to lemmatize

It returns the following error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'`
I tried many ways like using f function but in vain: `election.withColumn("filtered", lemmatize(f.col("filtered")))`

I also tried map and apply function on my dataframe and it threw this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'apply'`

Comment: check this out https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=udf#pyspark.sql.functions.udf

Comment: I am sorry but cannot find the solution using udf. I tried udf_lemma = udf(lambda x: lemmatize(x), StringType()) then udf_lemma(col("filtered"))

Comment: why would you do fullCorpus['filtered'] within the function? is the fullCorpus a dataframe or column? what is the type of the column string?